# How to install iPA to specific devices using Distribution Profile

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution

I have got a strange requirement from my client. I need to install iPA with distribution Profile to selected devices. Previously I have done the same with developer profile and Adhoc-Distribution profile. If I create iPA with distribution profile, however, I don't get any option to check UDID of the devices before installing. Third party MDMs are not permitted by the client.

I need a solution for checking the UDID of the devices by using distribution profile before installing.  MDMs are not permitted and I have already tried developer profile and Adhoc-Distribution profile.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to install iPA with distribution Profile to selected devices.

You are describing an Ad Hoc distribution. When you create the Ad Hoc distribution profile at the Member Center web site, you get to specify the devices. That is *exactly* what an Ad Hoc distribution is: an app associated with a list of specific devices that it can run on.

> But if i create iPA with distribution profile, i didn't get any option to check UDID of the devices before installing

With an Ad Hoc distribution profile, you specify the devices (by UDID) at the Member Center. You don't need any further "option". If you export for Ad Hoc distribution using this profile, the app *will not run* except on the listed devices, which precisely meets your requirements.

Comment: Alternatively, I suppose your client could set up an Enterprise developer membership, but I have no experience with that, and it seems like it might be overkill (but do draw their attention to it): https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/

Comment: Currently we are using Adhoc-Distribution profile. But while adding new devices to profile, the profile gets invalid and working iPA from client side stops working. In oder to solve this problem we need another solution.